# Getting conflicting implementation error while adding custom pallet

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

We had changed the code in pallet template and was trying to add it in substrate node-template runtime. Link to [[github](https://github.com/sky-vibhu/Customise-Pallet) code][2](https://github.com/sky-vibhu/Customise-pallet.git)

Got the following [image: error].

After answer updated following new error:  [image: error]

Error -
Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/data/Network-marketing/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/data/Network-marketing/runtime)`

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/data/Network-marketing/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-55554732df6f82a1/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
--- stdout
Information that should be included in a bug report.
Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/data/Network-marketing/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
Using rustc version: rustc 1.65.0-nightly (02654a084 2022-08-30)

--- stderr
Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/data/Network-marketing/runtime)
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `core::convert::TryFrom<OriginCaller>` for type `frame_system::RawOrigin<[type error]>`
--> /data/Network-marketing/runtime/src/lib.rs:284:1
|
284 |    construct_runtime!(
|   *^
|  |*|
| ||
285 | ||     pub enum Runtime
286 | ||     where
287 | ||         Block = Block,
...   ||
302 | ||     }
303 | || );
| ||_- in this macro invocation
...   |
|
= note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
- impl<T, U> TryFrom for T
where U: Into;
= note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` due to previous error`enter code here`

Comment: I've just checked out the linked repo and it compiled without giving any errors. Have you tried running `rustup update`?

Comment: yes I have tried rustup update... still not worked.

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong the files. I've changed the files please check it now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [this line](https://github.com/sky-vibhu/Customise-pallet/blob/main/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L8) in your custom pallet template:

```rust
pub use frame_system::pallet::*;
```

With this line, you have basically exported the entire `frame_system` Pallet into your file, which makes all of the pallet template imports look like frame system.

You should change this line to:

```rust
pub use pallet::*;
```

As seen here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L6

I am interested to know how you got to this error, and what you were trying to do. Does some tutorial tell you to do this?

Comment: No I am doing this on my own. Basically, I am trying to build a simple network marketing pallet in which you can add different people. Its just a start.

Comment: It is giving error after this also in the runtime. Now instead of 9 its giving just 1 runtime error.

Comment: I've have uploaded the new error, kindly look into it.

Comment: please open a new question, and do not put screenshots, but share the error as text.

Comment: I have uploaded the new code to the github link. I'll upload the errors.

Comment: Link to new question - https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4584/getting-conflicts-in-implementation-error-while-adding-custom-pallet

Comment: It's Solved. Thanks for support.